# how to relate the digitalus controls with their respective modules on a single page

Tags: php, zend-framework, content-management-system

how can i relate the ***digitalusControl*** with the ***digitalusModule*** so that when i change the module using the selectors in the back(admin area) it will also set it to the selected value in the front

```
  <digitalusControl type='moduleSelector' id='modulesearch' group='mods' />
  <digitalusModule type='modulesearch' group='mods' module='serach' action='search'/>
  <digitalusControl type='moduleSelector' id='modulenews' group='mods' />
  <digitalusModule type='modulenews' group='mods' module='blog' action='blog'/>
```

i am having a hard time since the forums don't have a relevant info on how to add multiple modules to a single page ..

**EDIT** let alone the relating thing how can i add multiple modules to a page using the digitalusControl tags i tried to do this but it's not working

```
<digitalusControl type='moduleSelector' id='modulesearch' group='mods' />
<digitalusControl type='moduleSelector' id='modulenews' group='mods' />
```

but when i add

```
<digitalusControl type='moduleSelector' id='module' group='mods' />
```

only this one (the third one) works the other two will not work when i try to see in the db they are saved like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<elementData><module>login_index</module><modulesearch>search_search</modulesearch><modulenews>blog_blog</modulenews><blog>41</blog></elementData>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a bug in digitalus it's now fixed in the repository you can fetch it from here fixed in revision 782

```
svn checkout http://digitalus-cms.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```